# Mocha is unable to find my dynamically generated tests?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

While generating the tests using a for loop the dynamic tests are detected in the framework. But for one specific suite I need to fetch data from database and create tests based on that. The program that I am using is as follows

```
 describe("Testing existence of elements", function (existence_suite_done) {

    let elements = [];
    models.cypher('match (a:page {id: "74ab8f9d-e24b-41d1-9390-d6fb338ece38"})-[r:child]->(b:element) return b;')
      .then((data) => {
        elements = data.records;
      })
      .then(() => {
        for(var i=0;i<elements.length;i++) {
          it('hello', (done) => {
            done();
          });
        }
      })
      .then(existence_suite_done)
      .catch(existence_suite_done);
  });
```

Now I am curious how to get that suite working specifically when the tests are dependent on results from a promise. I imagine it has something to do with scopes but am unable to figure out where I am going wrong. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Try to put fetching data inside `it(...)`.

Comment: @Sergey didn't work

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
// Your async data fetching emulation.
var models = {
    cypher: () => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout(function () {
                resolve({ records: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'] });
            }, 300);
        });
    }
};


// The data query is inverted with respect to the loop.
describe("Testing existence of elements", function () {
    let elements;

    it('Fething and testing data', () => {
        return models.cypher()
            .then((data) => {
                elements = data.records;
            })
            .then(() => {
                for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
                    var el = elements[i];
                    console.log(`Testing ${el} ...`);
                }
            });
    });
});
```

Alternately, instead of using the `done() callback`, you may return a `Promise` ([docs](https://mochajs.org/#working-with-promises)).

**P.S.**

It seems that Mocha does look for tests only within the describe's suite function. So, it won't be waiting for your data fetching async callback to look into it.

Here I found [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51859356/mocha-testing-inside-async-callbacks).